# Retrieve total sales for each product category in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I have two tables in my MySQL database: products and sales. The products table has the following structure:
Table: products

```
------------------------
| id | name    | category |
------------------------
| 1  | Product A | Electronics |
| 2  | Product B | Clothing    |
| 3  | Product C | Electronics |
| 4  | Product D | Furniture   |
| 5  | Product E | Clothing    |
| ...| ...      | ...         |
------------------------
```

The sales table records the sales transactions with the following structure:
Table: sales

```
------------------------
| id | product_id | quantity |
------------------------
| 1  | 1          | 5        |
| 2  | 2          | 10       |
| 3  | 1          | 3        |
| 4  | 4          | 8        |
| 5  | 2          | 2        |
| ...| ...        | ...      |
------------------------
```

I want to retrieve the total sales quantity for each product category. The result should display the category name and the sum of quantities sold for products in that category.

Desired Result:

```
------------------------
| category     | total_sales |
------------------------
| Electronics  | 8           |
| Clothing     | 12          |
| Furniture    | 8           |
------------------------
```

Could you please provide me with the SQL query to achieve this result? I'm new to SQL and would greatly appreciate your help. Thank you!

Comment: What did you try yourself? This has the feel of a homework question. See also [asking](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

You need a join between the two tables followed by an aggregation:

```sql
SELECT p.category, COALESECE(SUM(s.quantity), 0) AS total_sales
FROM products p
LEFT JOIN sales s
    ON s.product_id = p.id
GROUP BY p.category;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
SELECT a.id, a.name, COALESCE(d.Totalsales, 0) AS Totalsales
FROM Products  a
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT product_id, SUM(quantity) AS Totalsales
    FROM Sales
    GROUP BY product_id
) d ON a.id = d.product_id;
```